# Structure of encrypted office files

Tags: file-encryption

I try to find out the structure of encrypted office files (I'd like to implement something like a carving tool for finding certain encrypted file types). I try to understand the [Office Document Cryptography Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313071%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but this seems to be very hard, probably because this is too MS specific. What I found out is that when encrypting DOCX-Files, the file header changes from `50 4B 03 04` (typical docx-header) to `D0 CF 11 E0` (typical doc header). Within the file I found a XML-File describing the used algorithm, key length, MACs, etc (`XmlEncryptionDescriptor`). Does anybody know the general structure and how it changes when encrypting?

I hope this question is not too specific.